# transfer large chunks of data between devices running the app

Tags: iphone, ios

My game require I transfer a large amount of data between the devices playing. I have been using game kit to transfer over bluetooth but it simply can't keep up. What other methods can I use to transfer data between iOS devices (inside my game)?

So I'm looking to connect two devices that are on the same wifi network. I was thinking having one device as a master and run a ssh server but I can't find any iOS ssh server libraries out there.

The second option is a good 'ol socket connection but I have not been able to find anything (useful) on that either.

Is there any standard way apart from using a server or game kit - Any actual fast peer 2 peer methods?

Answer (score 0):

There is a peer-to-peer framework that just added ios capabilities called Alljoyn. https://www.alljoyn.org/ I've never used but I have heard good things

Answer (score 0):

I just got around to implementing transferring substantial data via GameKit.  I highly recommend chunking, and having a look at this project:  https://github.com/borealkiss/BKSessionController.   My project was moving images and data (stored in Core Data) via chunking.  I realize this is an old question, but I thought it would be good to finally give back to the community.