# Passing object/NSData between iOS devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata, game-center

I'm creating a game, turn based, and I was thinking of using Game Center to handle it, but the passed game-object is evidently max 64kb. Is there another way to pass objects between devices for this use, without having to create a database or storage-server as middle man? The game-object itself for me is probably a lot less than 64kb, but there are some initial variables I would like to send, such as images. With my calculations, the initial data for one game is about 500kb, but after getting those images once, the passed game object is just a couple of kb's, and are never going to include those images again.

Is there a way to send these images directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to get around the limit.

This answer mentions [Alljoyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14631111/793607)  which would allow you to transfer that size of files.

You could also send them indirectly by transferring them to your own server, then passing a link to the file to the other player.  For a turn based game, this would have good advantages of enhanced reliability as you could put in retries on error for both the upload to the server and the download to the device and control it yourself.  I would recommend AFHTTPClient for this, also.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into Alljoyn, but it seemed quite crazy. And more suited for proximity-games I guess. I'll look into AFHTTPClient, sounds more like my match. I do have a server, but not much space, but I guess I could upload the initial game-file(images etc.) once, send a link to it to the other player, and when the other player has downloaded it, it could delete it from the server as well, and save it locally? I'll have to play a bit with this idea, and find out what's possible.

Comment: If you have server capacity, it gives you many options, like persistent stored games for a user, in case the user loses or resets their device, or wants to have it on multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to pass objects between devices for this use, without having to create a database or storage-server as middle man?

Without your own server, there isn't.